# Is "unfiltered-Camel-smoking war veteran" hyphenated correctly?

Tags: hyphenation

We hyphenate the adjective "five-year-old" as such, but what about "unfiltered-Camel-smoking war veteran"? Should it be "unfiltered Camel-smoking war veteran" instead? Does hyphenating adjectives apply to this sort of description?

Comment: I opt for the first. The second implies that the war veteran, themself, is 'unfiltered' which I would not wish upon them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphens are partial indications of the structure of a complicated noun compound.  Brackets or parentheses would work better, but hyphens are conventional.  Your example, using brackets to show the structure, is

```
       [[[unfiltered Camel] smoking] [war veteran]]
```

which means "veteran of a war who smokes unfiltered Camel cigarettes"

Using hyphens instead and beginning at the bottom of the tree structure, you eliminate a pair of brackets by replacing all space characters enclosed by the brackets with hyphens:

```
      [[unfiltered-Camel smoking] [war-veteran]]

      [unfiltered-Camel-smoking war-veteran]

      unfiltered-Camel-smoking-war-veteran
```

Choose the one of these which seems least confusing, then omit any brackets left over.